# Having trouble connecting to iSeries from .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, db2, db2-400, iseries-navigator

This is a follow-up from the following question: [Having trouble connecting to iSeries from .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818229/having-trouble-connecting-to-iseries-from-net-core/63967427)

The initial problem was resolved by setting a port number. I'm now running into the problem of the connection seemingly opening, however, hanging on the actual `.Open()` step - IE, never continuing on to the next line of code. For reference, here's my code block:

```
public static DB2Connection GetDatabaseConnection(string connectionString)
{
    DB2Connection DB2Connection = new DB2Connection(connectionString);

    DB2Connection.SystemNaming = true;

    try
    {
    DB2Connection.Open();
    return DB2Connection;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    throw ex;
    }
}
```

And my connection string is in this format: `Server=###.###.###.###:#####;Database=DATABASE;UID=USER;PWD=PASSWORD;LibraryList=LIBRARY,LIST`

Looking at the logs on the i Navigator, I see that there is a job name `Qzhqssrv` when is opened, with the user `Quser`, status `Running`, and type `Prestart batch - Server`. Looking into the logs for that entry, I see `Job #####/QUSER/QZHQSSRV started on DATE at TIME in subsystem QUSRWRK in QSYS. Job entered system on DATE at TIME`. However, it doesn't seem to continue beyond that.

Looking at the logs for a similar operation, when I'm connecting via Access Client Solutions, I get considerably more information and more steps in the logs. This leads me to believe that the system is waiting for me to send further information, however, my application is still stuck on `.Open()` - so perhaps there is something else I was supposed to send as part of the `.Open()` instruction. If so, I'm not sure what it would be.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which port do you try to connect to ? I think the good answer is what you get when issuing greeen screen `WRKSRVTBLE SERVICE('drda')` (446 by default)

Next problem may be you need a license, can't help you for that

Comment: 446 does indeed get the licensing error! Is 446 the port that would be used if I wanted to execute stored procedures on the server?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this topic out - the problem was indeed the lack of a license. Connecting on port 446 was the correct approach, and once we got a license, we were able to get the connection working. Thanks @nfgl!

Comment: Hey Kiran, we are currently also facing issues when connecting from .NET Core 3.1 to DB2 iSeries. Just to get things right: did you use the [IBM.Data.DB2.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core/3.1.0.300) package to access an iSeries DB2? And your most prevalent issues were with the port and the license?

Comment: Yeah - those two sorted it out. However, there were a whole pile of tangential issues we faced when trying to get this to work using an Azure Web Service. In the end, we abandoned the web service and went with an Azure VM instead, since we couldn't get the license to be recognized using the web service.

Comment: Thanks for the info!